# get month from 2013/12/02 in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have database with Name, email, joindate and my Query is

```
$name=$_POST['txtname'];
$email=$_POST['txtemail'];
$date = date("Y/m/d");

INSERT INTO member (name,email,joindate) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$date')
```

output

Name: Raj
Email: test@test.com
Date: 2013/12/02

I have lots of members, then how i able output member by month

Can any one help me to sort it.

I want to get detail by month into another page.

how to get the month from 2013/12/02 mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`YEAR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year), [`MONTH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month), and [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    member 
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(joindate, "%Y/%m/%d")),
    MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(joindate, "%Y/%m/%d"))
```

Comment: I guess what he is looking for is `GROUP` *I have lots of members, then how i able output member by month*

Comment: i hope you can give me better answer